# Popup if IE8 compatibility

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have been searching the web looking for answers...here is what I need that I am not getting.

Pre-information

Running a Wordpress site

Site isn't loading correctly when using IE8 Compatibility (9 is fine).

Have implemented the quick fix

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

and even

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

This does not solve the issue.

I need a javascript solution for various reasons

The idea is that when a user has compatibility mode turned on, a message will appear that tells the user to turn it off.

I know that this has something to do with it but I don't know how to code it in javascript to do something.

```
IE8 Compatibility View: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`X-UA-Compatible` (either meta element or HTTP response header) with `IE=edge` value reliably prevents user from switching to compatibility mode by clicking button at the right of location bar — since the button is not shown at all when `X-UA-Compatible` with `IE=edge` value is present.

Ability to switch modes via developer tools (opening via F12 key) is not an issue — this is development feature which state does not persist after browser is restarted so is totally safe and is not something to care about.

However, if page works incorrectly in IE8 compatibility mode, then it very likely works incorrectly in real IE8 too. So if support for IE8 is important for you, you should fix issues related to IE8 itself, not to compatibility-mode feature.